# permalink issue with big number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permalinks

i'm having a issue trying to make my urls user friendly.

This is the url i have, well a variation

```
3309050323-aa-aaaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaa-11-2016
```

However i get this error appear when using the url

```
3309050323 is out of range for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer with limit 4
```

The issue is the the first is a tex area (was a string but i changed it to check if thats the issue)

Heres the migration

```
  def self.up
    add_column :events, :permalink, :text
    add_index :events, :permalink
  end
  def self.down
    remove_column :events, :permalink
  end
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working??

The links were working lovely until i added the first set of numbers, i kinda need to add the numbers into the url to make the url unique to its event.

Thanks
Sam

**Edit**

```
 t.text     "permalink"
    t.string   "custom_event_id"
  end

  add_index "events", ["permalink"], name: "index_events_on_permalink", using: :btree
```

This is my `schema.rb`, I'm wondering if the index has anything to do with it?

Comment: What is your controller code doing with the params it receives?

Comment: @event = Event.find_by_permalink(params[:id]) Thats the controller code that uses it

Comment: What are the other columns on the table?

Answer (score 0):

3309050323 is out of range for an integer column in postgres

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html

try a bigint instead.

Comment: but its a text column, not an integer!

Comment: Thats not what your stack trace is telling you.  Try running: psql <your database> then \d+ events.  Thats one way to see the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this indexes

```
add_index :events, :permalink
```

If will not help. Try to generate string unique prefix instead of digits